# tar: Cannot connect to C: resolve failed fatal: Not a valid object name C in gitbash

Tags: git, cloc

i need to run below command in gitbash

```
$ loc_count="$(cloc-1.92.exe --git --diff ${start_commit} ${end_commit})"
```

but i am getting this error

> tar: Cannot connect to C: resolve failed
>
> fatal: Not a valid object name C

how resolve this?

Comment: Can you show us the contents of `$start_commit` and `$end_commit`? Does this command work without the `$(...)` syntax, just run directly?

Comment: branch=master
start_date=2021-01-20
end_date=2021-02-20

start_commit="$(git rev-list -n1 --before=${start_date} ${branch})"
end_commit="$(git rev-list -n1 --before=${end_date} ${branch})"

echo "Start commit for ${start_date} is ${start_commit}
echo "End commit for ${end_date} is ${end_commit}
Using this, you can plug $start_commit and $end_commit into your cloc command:

loc_count="$(cloc --git --diff ${start_commit} ${end_commit})"
echo "$loc_count"

Comment: @joanis in gitbash we can't run any command without $

Comment: I meant can you run  `cloc-1.92.exe --git --diff ${start_commit} ${end_commit}` by itself and let the output go to terminal.

Comment: Thanks for showing more of your code. It would be a lot easier to read if you edited it right into the question, though. I stand by my original comment, though: for troubleshooting, strip away the script and run `cloc.1.92.exe --git --diff HEAD <some-other-commit>` and tell us if that works. No, you don't need to type `$` to run a command in GitBash. `$(...)` is for capturing the output of a command into a variable, but unecessary to run a command.

Comment: yes its working in command prompt and i got the output thank you so much

Comment: Good, that's one helpful step. Now I'm not sure if you still have a problem. If something still doesn't work, please edit the question to make it clear what's not working and compare the output of the command on its own vs the script, or if your problem is now solved,please confirm that too.